# How to replace specific elements in a textarea with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea, where I'm displaying HTML data coming from my Database. Within that data there are several `<a href=""></a>` links. Some of them has a class some of them don't.

Sample html code:

```
<textarea class="txt-area">This <a href="http://myeaxmple.com/">contents</a>. a <span>test</span> document. Please <a class="my-class" href="http://facebook.com/">do</a>. ignore it's <a class="my-class" href="http://google.com/">contents</a>.</textarea>
```

My question is, that how is it possible to search for those anchor tags (whithin the textarea) which has the specific class added and replace their `HREF` attribute?

Comment: You will not be able to get jQuery's DOM based access to those elements that are content of textarea. The best way I see it possible is to use Regex, identify all the anchor tags and then for each tag find out if your class is set and then change the HREF attr. All 3 steps will need to be done separately using Regex. I will try to post a detailed answer if you need it, but in some time

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: I agree. Don't know what I was thinking. Really my bad!

Comment: @RGraham ahah, does upvoting a comment that said downvote count as a downvote?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Lol! Definitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just parse the HTML with jQuery and play with it. You can then update the value after :

```
var $textarea = $('.txt-area');

var $html = $('<div>').html($textarea.val());

$html.find('.my-class').attr('href', 'newHREF');

$textarea.val($html.html());
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5VvfH/

Comment: You are right that if textarea have text value then we need to add it in div but if it has html then we not need to add it in div, i just only want to mention it.

Comment: @Sid The reason he's doing that is to pump the "original" content back into the textarea again.

Comment: @Sid inserting it in a div (or any html element) make it easier. else the `a` would be in the root so you'd need to use `filter` instead of `find`. Then if inside the `textarea` there is a `<div><a>..</a></div>` filter will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to exploit this by inserting some malicious code when placing back the content?

Comment: @Radical_Activity it seem like `script` tags aren't running : http://jsfiddle.net/5VvfH/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Alright, thank you. Also to where is it creating that `<div>` element? I don't really understand why isn't that displaying on the page with the textarea's content.

Comment: @Radical_Activity the div is just in the memory, it is never append to de DOM. When using `.html()` only take what's inside the tag. Basically, it is just a box *"outside"* the page. You take what is inside that box and move in inside an other box (which is the `textarea`).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ah I understand it now. Thank you very much for the answer. it is working very well as expected!

Comment: Another interestign questions is that why is it placing `&amp;` instead of an `&` sign?

Comment: @Radical_Activity unfortuantly, that's `.html()` converting character to entities. You can use that in the `.val()` : `$html.html().replace(/&amp;/g, '&')`. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5VvfH/2/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thank you, it is working now perfectly. Thanks for the input man I really appriciate it!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Is it dangerous if I place `document` instead of `<div>`, so I can display all HTML code including all tags?

Comment: @Radical_Activity Yes, it will cause an error. You cant use `.html` on document. You can however have a `div` result and output your html, but then, script tag will be interpreted : http://jsfiddle.net/5VvfH/3/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thank you. What if I'm using '<html>'? Its seems to be working okay.

Comment: @Radical_Activity it doesnt really matter what's inside the `$('<div>)`, it could be `$('<hellokitty>')` and it will work. It will create a node in the memory only. If you use a selector on the other hand, it will be different. It will totally erase you html inside that selector. That being said, `$('html')` will **not** work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I understand that I can't use selectors, however in my above comment I've mentioned `<html>` tag. Is it okay to use? Actually it is working for me.

Comment: @Radical_Activity yes, i understood that, and my answer was *"it doesnt really matter what's inside the $('<div>), it could be $('<hellokitty>') and it will work."* So yes `<html>` is okay :)

Answer (score 3):

First get value of text-area and then replace that class values

```
var htmlData = $('<div>').html($(".txt-area").val());
   $(htmlData).find("a.ReqClass").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("href"));
  // and if you want to replace it then
  $(this).attr("href","newHref");
});
```